# Vue-router renders two components at once when switching rutes

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When switching between *(sub)* sub-routes, for a short while both sidebar components are rendered at once (`ModalityMap.SidebarModalities` and `ModalityMap.SidebarVehicleInfo`).

That seems so weird, it has never occurred to me before. Feels like it has to be something easy, maybe something i overlooked in the documentation. Or am I wrong and this is standard behavior?

*It is a problem because the sidebars have different widths and even stacked on top of each other they do not overlap completely overflowing the one rendered above.*

Excerpt from my routing

```
   ...
        {
            path: '/map',
            component: ModalityMap.Base,
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'modality_map_view',
                    path: '',
                    components: {
                        main: ModalityMap.HomeView,
                        sidebar: ModalityMap.SidebarModalities
                    }
          ...
                },
                {
                    name: 'modality_map_view_vehicle',
                    path: 'vehicle/:vehicleId',
                    components: {
                        main: ModalityMap.HomeView,
                        sidebar: ModalityMap.SidebarVehicleInfo
                    }
          ...
                }
```

...

Comment: Try adding `/` in path to `modality_map_view`

Comment: Didn't change anything